# How to read the database name and the ldf file name from mdf file in c# without attaching to SQL server?

Tags: c#, sql

Is there any way to get **database name** and **ldf (log) file name** without attaching to SQL server. How SQL server read this information before attaching? I know that OrcaMDF will parse the mdf file and get information, but its specified that only supported in SQL server 2008, it is possible to get this information from 2005,2008,2012 SQL server mdf files. I don't want any other information only database name and ldf file name is enough.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474498/sql-smo-how-to-get-path-of-database-physical-file-name

Comment: That's a different question about getting the path of the physical file and it requires connecting to the database server. In this case I think the OP knows the path and wants to obtain meta data from the file without it being mounted in a SQL instance.

Comment: Just from a brief look at the OrcaMDF project (hadn't heard of it before, looks like it could be very useful), although 2008R2 was the target they suggest that 2005 (and therefore by extension probably 2008) is very similar and it should work with those too, which might be a start. Also, Mark Rasmussen seems to still be actively developing it (he was working on a new feature in March) but I guess you might have to get the source from Github and try to extend to 2012 if ti doesn't already work. Will keep an eye on this as it's an interesting question.

Comment: OrcaMDF has no direct way of giving you the database or ldf file names, especially not across versions. That being said, the "easiest" way of accomplishing it cross-version would be to use the methodology outlined here: http://improve.dk/sql-server-corruption-recovery-when-all-else-fails/. Figure out the boot page record format and you can get the database name. AFAIK the log files paths are only stored in the master database, so not sure if you can get those from the DB itself.