# Use a cast in a foreach

Tags: powershell

I'd like to add a cast to my foreach loop, but something is not working.
I'm trying to do:

```
ForEach ([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database] $mydb in $smo.Databases)
{
    # todo
}
```

But that does not work:

[image]

From samples online, I can only deduce that this should just work. I have `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest`, and ps version: `5.1.18362.145`

It works without the cast, but then intellisense does not which i would like.

Comment: Heads up that ISE is [no longer in active feature development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.1#support). Try [Azure Data Studio](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2020/11/12/the-november-2020-release-of-azure-data-studio-is-now-available/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). FYI [Jupyter, Mathematica, and the Future of the Research Paper](https://paulromer.net/jupyter-mathematica-and-the-future-of-the-research-paper/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.1#syntax.) doesn't show a way to cast within the `foreach` header:

```
foreach ($<item> in $<collection>){<statement list>}
```

You could cast within the loop body though:

```
ForEach ($mydb_ in $smo.Databases)
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database] $mydb = $mydb_
    # Should have intellisense for $mydb
}
```

Comment: Hm - so you're saying its not possible? because  look at for example this answer, this does have some kind of casting in the foreach, but i may not understand correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35670437/4122889

Comment: lol you're absolutely right. C# is what i program in normally, i did not even see it. Anyways, seems like this is the way to go then, thanks.